# ReadingLine in SR, and accessing lastline with index -1

Tags: c#, streamreader

i am writing atm, a streamreader tool, and have following problem. I read a line by ReadLine(); Then the stream, continues with the next line. But i need information about the last character (especially if it is a NewLine or a Linefeed) from the line before.

This is my approach:

I tried several approaches, with readblock or so. But it seems, that the stream itself, does not allow me, to get back in the position, to parse the elements i needed.

```
off = 0;
FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
using (StreamReader content = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    String s = "";
    while ((s = content.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        content.BaseStream.Seek((a == 0)? off: off - 1, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        //content.BaseStream.Seek(off, SeekOrigin.Current);
        var c=content.Peek();
        char b = (char)c;
        data = s;
        maxlist.Add(data.Length);
        if (data != null)
        {
              offset = offset + (data.Length)+2;
              offsetindex.Add(offset);
        }
        a++;
        off = off + data.Length - 2;
    }
    content.Close();
}
```

The expected Output should be, that i can access, the line above, after the Readline is called.So i can read with ReadBlock, the last elements, that i needed for exact positioning in the stream.

Comment: Might it be easier to just store a reference to the previous line of text as you loop around?

Comment: Readline, does not include Newline or Linefeeds

Comment: You my want to use the `Read` method to read one character at a time, that should give you the new line characters and allow you to keep track of what was at the end of the last line